# Will a SQL update query using a WHERE IN clause containing potentially a lot of row id's that won't match be an performance issue?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of inactive_products in an XML file.  I need to update the "active" (boolean) field of products I have in a DB based on the list of inactive products.  However, the list of inactive products contains a lot of products that are not even in my DB.  Will it be faster to just run an UPDATE statement using a WHERE IN clause with the entire list of inactive products, or should I compare the list of inactive products with a CSV file of active products first, to obtain the relevant inactive products, and then run an UPDATE statement with all this filtered list instead?

My initial thought is that I should just let SQL do its thing and handle the unfiltered list, but what is the technically correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to work around long list of values of IN operator is to JOIN to temporary table instead. It was the workaround back when Oracle didn't support more than 1000 values for IN.

If you have query like this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column IN (value1, value2, ..., valueN)
```

then replace it with:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS
SELECT column FROM <source that contains value1, value2, ..., valueN>

SELECT * FROM mytable JOIN temp_table ON (mytable.column = temp_table.column)
```

Asymptotically this should perform better than using IN (at least in Oracle).

Comment: What if the source is an XML file and not a SQL Table?  Would I just create a temporary table from the XML file?  And also, what statement could I run to update the rows that match between the two tables?

Comment: xml is xml - you got to get its data into database one way or another (somehow you did get them into your sql IN operator, right?)

Comment: quickly googled "update join mysql" and found that it's a standard feature: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/cross-table-update/

Comment: gotcha, so if i create a temporary table for this (since I don't really need the data other than for this update), what would be the UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend letting SQL do the filtering, which is essentially letting the database do the heavy lifting since its what it does best, however make sure that you have indexes on the id columns for better performance.

If this becomes too slow then you can look at filtering the list first.